# Django/Python: Loop over selected form fields in Django template

Tags: django, forms, templates, for-loop

I have a form with n fields. The first 4 fields should be displayed differently in my template then the rest of the form. Therefore, I was wondering if I can somehow loop over the first 4 fields, end the loop and continue looping over the rest of the fields later in the template.

```
        <table>
            {% for field in form %}
            {% if forloop.counter == 4 <<< Break here >>>%}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ field.label_tag }} </td>
                <td> {{ field }} </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        .... Different code ....
        <table>
            {% for field in form %} <<< Continue here >>>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ field.label_tag }} </td>
                <td> {{ field }} </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

I have found [this code](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2093/) but I was wondering if I could structure the template differently or if I have missed some new changes in Django 1.3 which allow the breaking of loops now.

Normally, I would split the form in two seperate forms, but I would like to reuse the form definition in other templates as well, therefore I would like to keep all information together in one form.

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same solution as other "can't do it in the template" problems: do it in the view. I truly believe added complexity and further separation of logic into multiple code areas (tags, new files, etc.) only hurts maintainability. I separate / implement DRY only when things actually do get repetitive, unreadable, etc.

Everything else is premature optimization.

Django won't know the difference when a form is submitted.

```
fields = list(form)    
part1, part2 = fields[:4], fields[4:]


{% for field in part1 %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
...
{% for field in part2 %}{{ field }}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: list(Form) gives me "'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' object is not iterable".  Why do you use lower case 'form' in the line that reads list(form)?  Presumably in the view the name of the form class is upper case: 'Form'.  Thanks.  I'm trying to get a list of the Form's fields.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you write your own [custom template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). Perhaps your filter could look like this:

```
def show_part(form,section=1): 
    display = ''
    for id,field in enumerate(form):  
         if int(section) == 1 and id > 3:
             break
         elif int(section) == 2 and id < 3:
             continue
         display += '<tr><td>'+field.label_tag+'</td>'
         display += '<td>'+field+'</td></tr>'
    return display
```

and use the following in your template:

```
<table>
    {{ form|show_part:"1" }}
</table>
<table>
    {{ form|show_part:"2" }}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since form is a list, you could also use Django's built-in slice template filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Your example would become:

```
    <table>
        {% for field in form|slice:":4" %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ field.label_tag }} </td>
            <td> {{ field }} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    .... Different code ....
    <table>
        {% for field in form|slice:"4:" %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{ field.label_tag }} </td>
            <td> {{ field }} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: is it work? I have tried your solution but does not work to me. But I improve your code once slicing `{% for field in form.visible_fields|slice:":4" %}` and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, if you just add

```
<table>
{% if forloop.counter <= 4 %}
... first four fields
{% else %}
... other fields
{% endif %}
```

If you need two different tables you could add:

```
{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
<table>
{% endif %}

{% if forloop.last %}
</table>
{% endif %}
```

That's not a very pretty solution, but it works. You could also consider using two forms.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter than "Yuji 'Tomita' Tomita" answer

Make list for form on your view:

```
context = {'form': list(form)}
return render(request, template, context)
```

and get each field on template by |slice

```
{% for field in form|slice:":4" %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ field.label_tag }} </td>
        <td> {{ field }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```